# Elastic search - scala case class @timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I want to save data into Elasticsearch using Spark.
I use this connector: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-installation

I can save data using saveToEsWithMeta method on RDD with a case class. But when I want to set field named @timestamp I have a problem. I added an attribute name `@timestamp` into my case class but this attribute is saved with name '$attimestamp' in Elasticsearch instead of '@timestamp'.

I found a workaround using a Map instead of a case class, but do you know a solution using a case class?

Thanks a lot,
Benoît

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this from the documentation you linked to:

> For cases where the id (or other metadata fields like ttl or
>   timestamp) of the document needs to be specified, one can do so by
>   setting the appropriate mapping namely es.mapping.id. Following the
>   previous example, to indicate to Elasticsearch to use the field id as
>   the document id, update the RDD configuration (it is also possible to
>   set the property on the SparkConf though due to its global effect it
>   is discouraged):
>
> EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))

Comment: I try it but it's not working. I believe @timestamp is part of data and not part of metadata. "es.mapping.timestamp" refers to _timestamp metadata. I'm wrong?